# Multiselection logic in Devexpress TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, devexpress

I have problem with creating multi selection logic to `DevExpress` `TreeView`.

I have interface for `treeItem` and 3 derived classes (f.e. Drive, Directory, File)

I want to add logic something like

- Only multiple files can be selected
- Is user want to select more than 1 drive or Directory, only one (last) item should be selected
- If there are selected f.e. 2 files and user CTRL and click on dir or drive, selection should contains only last item (in this case dir or drive)

Now i have sth like this:

```
<dxg:GridControl
  SelectedItems = "{Binding Selection.SelectedItems, Mode=OneWay}"
  SelectionChanged="Grid_OnSelectionChanged"
  SelectedItemChanged="Grid_OnSelectedItemChanged">    
  <dxg:GridControl.View>
    <dxg:TreeListView MultiSelectMode = "Row"/>
  </dxg:GridControl.View>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

And in code behind:

```
private void MachinesGrid_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, GridSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  MyViewModel vm = (MyViewModel)DataContext;
  if (e.Action == CollectionChangeAction.Add)
  {
      if (item.Type == ItemType.Folder)
      {
         vm.Selection.ClearSelection();
         vm.Selection.AddToSelection(item);
      }
      else
      {
        vm.Selection.AddToSelection(item);
      }
   }
}

private void MachinesGrid_OnSelectedItemChanged(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
   TreeItem item = e.NewItem as TreeItem;
   if (item == null)
   {
      return;
   }
   MyViewModel vm = (MyViewModel)DataContext;
   vm.Selection.ClearSelection();
   vm.Selection.AddToSelection(item);
}
```

Problem is in

```
vm.Selection.ClearSelection();
```

because I'm changing it when its enumerating.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

May you could take a look into the [DevExpress help lib](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument7359). Its like the one from Microsoft called MSDN.

There is a [SelectedRowsCollection](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressXpfGridSelectedRowsCollectiontopic) property that you can bind into your VM and than simple `get` it from you bound property